# How do i randomly chooce a "def"?

Tags: python, python-3.x

take a look at this python 3 code.

```
import random
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk


def img1():

root = Tk()
root.geometry("400x400")

load = Image.open("1.png")
render = ImageTk.PhotoImage(load)
img = Label(image=render)
img.image = render
img.place(x=0,y=0)


def img2():

root = Tk()
root.geometry("400x400")

load = Image.open("2.png")
render = ImageTk.PhotoImage(load)
img = Label(image=render)
img.image = render
img.place(x=0,y=0)


def img3():

root = Tk()
root.geometry("400x400")

load = Image.open("3.png")
render = ImageTk.PhotoImage(load)
img = Label(image=render)
img.image = render
img.place(x=0,y=0)


def img4():

root = Tk()
root.geometry("400x400")

load = Image.open("4.png")
render = ImageTk.PhotoImage(load)
img = Label(image=render)
img.image = render
img.place(x=0,y=0)


def img5():

root = Tk()
root.geometry("400x400")

load = Image.open("5.png")
render = ImageTk.PhotoImage(load)
img = Label(image=render)
img.image = render
img.place(x=0,y=0)



def img6():

root = Tk()
root.geometry("400x400")

load = Image.open("6.png")
render = ImageTk.PhotoImage(load)
img = Label(image=render)
img.image = render
img.place(x=0,y=0)


List_img = [img1(), img2(), img3(), img4(), img5(), img6()]
random.choice(List_img)
```

I want to choose one image at random, but it keeps pushing all of them at once.

the last two lines are where it gets complicated.

I do not get an error.

Im fairly new to python so be nice <3

(So I have too much code with little text and i have to add more so bear with me c;)

Comment: Instead of posting more text to bypass the "too much code" rule, have you considered removing some of the code? For example, reducing the 6 identical functions to 3 or 2?

Comment: This question [is under discussion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366951/stack-overflow-policy-on-offensive-screennames) at our Meta site.

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to call one of the functions, put the functions themselves in the list, not the result of calling the functions.

The parentheses in `img1()` are how you call the function. If you just want to treat the function itself as a value, that’s just `img1`. So:

```
List_img = [img1, img2, img3, img4, img5, img6]
```

And then, of course, you have to call the one you choose. In the same way that `img1()` means to call the function `img1`, this:

```
random.choice(List_img)()
```

… means to call whatever function gets chosen by `random.choice`.

The key idea here is that functions are “first-class values”—you can stick them in lists, pass them to functions, store them in variables, etc., just like you can with numbers or strings, and then you can call them later.

Comment: @KKKonFleek the elements in the list are references to function-objects and they have to be invoked, `()` does exactly that.

Comment: @KKKonFleek I updated the answer to try to explain it in detail. Please let me know if it’s confusing. But really, What’s comment says 90% of what you need to know, in just one sentence.